# file and form upload at the same time using ajax in java web

Tags: java, html, jsp

i am having difficulties in trying to submit a form which includes the `image` of the user to the `database` using `ajax`. The form data alone works well but on including the `image` it throws a `FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException`

Is there another way of doing this without reloading the page. i will appreciate any help

**JSP FILE**

```
    <form id="doc_form" class="form-horizontal tasi-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

                                                <div class="modal-body">

                                                <div class="form-group" id="err">

                                                </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group has-success">    
                                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-lg-3" for="doc_Image">Doctor Image</label>

                                                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                            <img id="ppic" src="assets/img/ui-zac.jpg" class="img-circle " width="160" height="160" style="margin-left: 70px; margin-bottom: 20px;" />
                                                            <input name="d_Image" type="file" class="form-control" id="doc_image" size="50" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)">
                                                        </div>

                                                        <script type="text/javascript">

                                                            var loadFile = function (event){
                                                                var output = document.getElementById('ppic');
                                                                output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                                                            };


                                                        </script>

                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="form-group has-success">
                                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-lg-3" for="doctorID">Doctor ID</label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                            <input name="doc_ID" type="text" class="form-control" id="doctorID">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group has-success">
                                                        <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label col-lg-3" for="fName">First Name</label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                            <input name="doc_fName" type="text" class="form-control" id="doc_fName">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group has-success">
                                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-lg-3" for="sName">Second Name</label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                            <input name="doc_sName" type="text" class="form-control" id="doc_sName">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group has-success">
                                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-lg-3" for="inputError">Date Of Birth</label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                            <input name="doc_DOB" type="date" class="form-control" id="doc_dob">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="form-group has-success">
                                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-lg-3" for="inputError">Password</label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                            <input name="doc_pass" type="text" class="form-control" id="doc_pass">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-theme" type="button" id="submitDoc">Submit</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                            <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                                            <script type="text/javascript">

                                                $(document).ready(function () {

                                                    $('#submitDoc').click(function (event) {
                                                         event.preventDefault();
                                                        var d_fName = ('#doc_fName');

                                                        $.ajax({
                                                            type: 'POST',
                                                            data: $("#doc_form").serialize(),
                                                            url: "AddDoctorServlet",
                                                             enctype:'multipart/form-data',
                                                            success: function (result) {
                                                                   $('#err').html(result);
                                                            }

                                                        });
                                                    });
                                                });

                                            </script>
```

**Servlet**

```
     protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/plain");

    String doc_ID = request.getParameter("doc_ID");
    String fName = request.getParameter("doc_fName");
    String sName = request.getParameter("doc_sName");
    String pass = request.getParameter("doc_pass");

    String dob = request.getParameter("doc_DOB");

    InputStream inputStream = null;

    Part filePart = request.getPart("d_Image");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    if (doc_ID.isEmpty() || fName.isEmpty() || sName.isEmpty() || pass.isEmpty() || dob.isEmpty() ) {
        out.print("  <div id='err' class='alert alert-danger' style='margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;' >Error !Fields are empty </div>");
    } else {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();

        try {
            //convert string input to date
            java.util.Date result =  format.parse(dob);

            //add details to model

            DoctorModel doctorModel = new DoctorModel(0, fName, sName, pass, doc_ID, result,inputStream);

            //check if doc exists
            if (!doctorDao.checkDoctor(doctorModel)) {

                //if does not exist,,,add him/her

                if (doctorDao.addDoctor(doctorModel)) {
                    out.print("  <div id='err' class='alert alert-success' role='alert' style='margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;' >Doctor added successfully.... </div>");
                } else {
                    out.print("  <div id='err' class='alert alert-danger' role='alert' style='margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;' >Error in adding the doctor </div>");
                }

            }else{
                out.print("  <div id='err' class='alert alert-danger' role='alert' style='margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;' >A doctor with that id already exists.. </div>");
            }

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AddDoctorServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

**The error**

```
    04-Nov-2016 08:58:22.877 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [AddDoctorServlet] in context with path [/SuperAdmin] threw exception [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8] with root cause
```

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.(FileUploadBase.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2734)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2643)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getPart(Request.java:2827)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getPart(RequestFacade.java:1089)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getPart(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:362)
    at controlla.AddDoctorServlet.processRequest(AddDoctorServlet.java:54)
    at controlla.AddDoctorServlet.doPost(AddDoctorServlet.java:123)

Comment: My wizard powers are still dormant, so, can you post your html form code...and also the method that process the data in the server side pointing the line that throws the exception?

Comment: Yes it can be done via a form submission with a MIME type of "multipart/form-data", but both your client side HTML/JS and server side code have to support that MIME type and submission method.

Comment: @Hackerman i have added the code..

Comment: @BrianC how can you do that? A sample code will be helpful

Comment: If you do not know how to set the MIME type then this project is way beyond where you are at.   You need to focus on getting basic HTML skills before moving on to server side work.

Comment: @BrianC i got the answer thank you and yes we all forget at some time, i am not a beginer